# How to do complex querying with logical operations by using searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, logical-operators, searchkick

Iam using **searchkick** library as an elasticsearch client for Product searching.
https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

It is possible to create 'OR' condition and 'AND' condition;

**AND operation**
Product.search where: {price: {lte: 200}, in_stock: true}

**OR operation**
Product.search where: {or: [[{in_stock: true}, {backordered: true}]]}

But Iam stuck with creating **multiple 'AND' 'OR'** conditions with searchkick.

I need something like

A OR B OR ( C AND D )

or I need like this,

A AND B AND ( C OR D )

Please guide me, how to achieve this

Thanks

Comment: Got the answer
A OR B OR ( C AND D ) 
Product.search where: {or: [[{brand: 'nike'}, {in-stock: true}, {price: {lte: 12}, color: 'red'}]]}
A AND B AND ( C OR D )
Product.search where: {brand: 'nike', in-stock: true, or: [ [{price: {lte: 12}}, {color: 'red'}] ]}

Comment: You should answer your own question. That way you help the community by highlighting the answer and indicating that this problem was solved. Also you'll get points ;)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A OR B OR ( C AND D )

```
Product.search where: {or: [[{brand: 'nike'}, {in-stock: true}, {price: {lte: 12}, color: 'red'}]]}
```

A AND B AND ( C OR D )

```
Product.search where: {brand: 'nike', in-stock: true, or: [ [{price: {lte: 12}}, {color: 'red'}] ]}
```

*Update*

(A OR B) AND (C OR D)

```
 Product.search where: {or: [[ {or: [[{brand: "nike"}, {in-stock: "true"}]]}], [{or: [[{price: 100}, {color: "red"}]]}]]}
```

Comment: Why the hell or condition has double square brackets, I spent so much time figuring out it has double square brackets. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Dias. Did you figure out how to do (A OR B) AND (C OR D)

Comment: Should be in the official documentation.  Life saver

Answer (score 0):

For (A OR B) AND (C OR D) it should be (no double brackets needed):

```
where: { _and: [ { _or: [ {A}, {B} ] }, { _or: [{C}, {D}] } ] }
```